# Ionic Framework compile html/js files

Tags: ionic-framework, obfuscation

When I finish an app, and I would distribute it to the App Store or Play Store, all the html and javascript files are accessable by end-user.
Is it possible to securely save those files in compiled folder or something that it is not readable?

Answer (score 2):

I use the [ionic-minify](https://github.com/Kurtz1993/ionic-minify) library to compress and obfuscate ionic projects:

```
npm install ionic-minify --save-dev
```

> Usage
>
> Just run ionic prepare  or ionic build  with the
>   --minify flag or set the alwaysRun attribute inside the configuration file to true.

The source will still be accessible by the end user (just like any other website) but minification will make it harder for the end user to understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some tricks like :

1. JS code [minifying](http://jscompress.com/).
2. Compile using [android studio](http://www.codenutz.com/getting-started-phonegap-android-studio/).
3. Encrypt [(Obfuscating JavaScript)](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx)